I want to write an academic book but I am unsure if I am structuring it right
To make it easy to write, I plan for each chapter to be basically its own 15-20 page essay. However, the book will be separated into parts (50+ pages), with each part having a central thesis which is supported by the essays in that part.  Each part will have an introduction to explain the context of the chapters in that part.
My book is meant to focus on the whole of Roman history.  I plan to divide the book into parts to enable me to focus on one part at a time while writing. Accordingly, the parts are supposed to be able to stand as individual research papers.

If what you want to express has the structure you describe, then that is the appropriate structure for it.
Scholarly monographs have all kinds of internal structures, depending on their subject matter and presentation. A book-length report on the archeological findings at one dig is structured differently than an overview of the historical development of a technology or the presentation of a sociological theory.
The only danger I see is that you may have had the idea for the book structure first (every chapter an essay, essays of a certain length, a certain number of essays to every part of your book, etc.), and that you now try to force the matter you want to present into that structure. I would always adapt the length of my chapters, for example, to how much there is to say on a sub-topic. And I would only write a book full of separate essays if they were largely independent of each other (e.g. literature of the Romans, Roman conquests, food in ancient Rome, etc.; or each chapter the rule of one emperor). If my book had something like an argument or narrative arch that spanned the whole book, I wouldn't structure each chapter as an essay, but write a book-length "essay" instread.
But I don't know enough about your project to give a clear recommendation. I'd always look at similar books in your field and see how they do it and how you like the different approaches. Choose the one that you think fits your content best.

Yes I will give myself some leeway when it comes to the page count. Furthermore I think that my topics are varied enough to justify many essays. Thanks for the advice.
